# sencha touch map is not rendering into view

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch, I am trying to display map in my sencha touch application. here comes the code

```
Ext.define("trackit.view.GoogleMaps", {
           extend: 'Ext.Map',
           config: {
           mapOptions:{
                //my map options
           }
        }
});
Ext.define("trackit.view.trackMap", {
           extend: 'Ext.Panel',
           requires: "trackit.view.GoogleMaps",
           config: {
           layout:'fit',
           items: [{
                   docked: 'top',
                   xtype: 'toolbar',
                   ui: "light",
                   title: 'Track direction',
                   },
                   ]
           }
});
```

From the above code only toolbar is coming but not the map.Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you only require `trackit.view.GoogleMaps` but not render it. Give your `trackit.view.GoogleMaps` view an `xtype`:

```
xtype: 'GoogleMaps'
```

Then render it as an item inside your `trackit.view.trackMap` view after your `toolbar`:

```
items: [
    {
        docked: 'top',
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        ui: "light",
        title: 'Track direction',
    },

    {
        xtype: 'GoogleMaps'     
    } 
]
```

Comment: It should works. Take a look at this demo: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#GJqsv#feLMg

Comment: @sudheer make sure you've included map api script also.

Comment: @phobos... I have included the script in index file itself, but still it is showing white blank page

Comment: @sudheer Then what's difference with your code with my demo above that make your code does not work? Can you create a sencha fiddle? I will try to help.

Comment: how? can u please post it. i am stuck.